# .htaccess example.com/contact displays example.com/contact.php (rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My link looks like this:

```
<a href='/contact'>Contact Us</a>
```

The web server needs to display the contents of the page `/contact.php`  WITHOUT redirecting.

Essentially, hiding filenames.

What do I add to `.htaccess` to achieve this?

Comment: This has not been answered for my purposes.  I'm trying to replace/hide filenames completely, with /someotherfolder that may NOT match the base filename.

For example:  mysite.com/contact  should display the contents of mysite.com/assets/contact-us.php

Similarly, and ideally, if someone browses to mysite.com/assets/contact-us.php, I would like a redirect to mysite.com/contact.  

This will require a new rule for each specific file, I realize.  But I haven't got anything to work.

Comment: Whilst you state "Essentially, hiding filenames", your example is not doing that; it is simply hiding the file extension. Please give an example of "hiding filenames".

Comment: Please update your question with your example of "hiding filenames" as this completely changes your original question. Also include the directives you have tried (in fact, your complete `.htaccess` file) and what happens exactly... do you get an error, undesired result, _nothing_? What you are trying to do requires a single rule, again something which has been answered many times - so why do these answers not work? Have you confirmed that `.htaccess` overrides are enabled etc.?